# Xamarin register logic

Tags: c#, .net, azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm actually doing some tests with Xamarin for a future project (Android and iOS) and I'm struggling on a problem.

I'm using Azure for my backend and a database. I know that I can log on social networks (Facebook, Twitter, ...) and use the "Authorize" attribute to notify the user that he needs to be authentificated, but how can I create my own ?

I want to let the user choose whether he wants to log in with his Facebook/Twitter account but, if he doesn't want to any of his social network accounts, I want to let him the choice to create a brand new account on my app as an alternative.

I know there is already the Azure AD B2C alternative but I don't have the accesses on the free subscription account I have at the moment. Could you also kindly tell me whether the option I added above is the best one for you as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cover this topic within the Azure Mobile Apps book - http://aka.ms/zumobook - chapter 2.  It covers custom providers such as Auth0, Azure AD B2C and custom authentication using forms that you generate within your app.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not what you're expecting as an answer! But why do you want to stick with typical sign up registration ?

Why not with OTP which would reduce the steps for the User at the initial stages of interaction with your app. Once that is done in the onboarding process you can collect all those required fields for your analytics.

I would suggest you to read about [Digits from twitter](https://fabric.io/kits/android/digits). Which is free and there is plenty of bindings available for xamarin through nuget package.

1. Digits-Xamarin https://www.nuget.org/packages/Digits-for-xamarin/
2. Digits XForms https://www.nuget.org/packages/Digits/